# CUDA Array summation on the 3rd dimension

Tags: cuda

I am new to CUDA. While writing a fast 3D array summation program on the 3rd dimension, there are some questions coming into my mind:

1. The most natural way is to use each matrix entry as threads, and each thread loops over the 3rd dimension. Under this scenario, is the memory considered coalesced? Since neighboring threads access neighboring elements; they only have strides on loop variables.
2. For improved performance, a reduction on the 3rd dimension certainly helps.
3. Are there any libraries to use? For 2D summation, using cuBLAS is considered a good choice. I am thinking of a forced type conversion, which cheats the compiler to regard the piece of memory as a 2D array, and using a matrix-vector multiplication from cuBLAS.

Comment: Have you considered using Thrust, provided to properly arrange the `3D` array in memory?

Comment: But the thrust library is not considered as a high performance library is it? For some reason I need high performance codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That's a coalesced read.
2. You can use cuBLAS in the same way. Just tell GEMV that the first (uncontracted) dimension is nx*ny.